# Disable button in a row table

Tags: php, jquery, css, javascript

I have a table with each rows have a Send Button:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="name"></td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Street AA</td>
            <td><a name="sendName" id="sendId" href="www.google.com">Send</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mr.XX</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Street XX</td>
            <td><a name="sendName" id="sendId" href="www.google.com">Send</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mr.YY</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Street YY</td>
            <td><a name="sendName" id="sendId" href="www.google.com">Send</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/ashashari/fCu4D/)

All values in that table I get from database. So what I want to do is, when the NAME value is empty, the send button will be disabled based on its row table.

Comment: How are you producing the above table?

Comment: Can you post your server-side code as well? (PHP)

Comment: Assign id to each td and then write a script which checks whether the name field is empty or not. If the name field is empty then the code must be redirected to:document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=true; else to:document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=false;

Comment: By the way if the names in the table are static then why do you need to disable the button.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to not put the button there if the database returns an empty name instead of removing it after. Something like

```
<a name="sendName" id="<? echo "id".&name; ?>" 
<? if (&name!="") echo 'href="#"'; ?>>Send</a>
```

or

```
<? if (&name=="") { ?>
  <span>Send</span>
<? } else { ?>
  <a name="sendName" id="<? echo "id".&name"; ?>" href="#">Send</a>
<? }  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no input values i do not quite understand why you want to use javascript for a task like this. If the value is empty simply do not display the link at all. Or remove the href-attribute add a css class and style the link different.

```
//disabled link
<a name="sendName" id="sendId">Send</a>
```

I don't know if this was a copy/paste error but you use the same ID `sendID` on all links.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below example code on send link :

`<?php if($row['NAME']==''){ echo 'Send' } else{?>
            <a name="sendName" id="sendId" href="www.google.com">Send</a>
            <?php }?>`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this jquery code for that you you need to include jquery library

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var objTR = $("table tr");
    for(var i = 0; i < objTR.length; i++)
    {
        var objCols = $(objTR[i]).children();
        var name = objCols[0].innerHTML;
        if(name == "")
            $(objCols[3]).find("a").removeAttr("href");
    }
});
</script>
```